# php usort multi-dimensional array using custom key and native calls

Tags: php

I need to sort an array of associative arrays by custom key using native calls.

Example

```
array(
    array('name' => 'abc', 'priority' => 5),
    array('name' => 'def', 'priority' => 7),
    array('name' => 'ghi', 'priority' => 2)
);
```

Need to sort the inner arrays using the `priority` key. This is done like so:

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['priority'] - $b['priority'];
});
```

However, I want to make a function that looks like this:

```
function sort_array_by_inner_key($array, $key) {
    usort($array, function($a, $b){
        return $a[$key] - $b[$key];
    });
    return $array;
}
```

Clearly the `$key` variable inside `function($a, $b)` will be null as we haven't assigned it. How can I pass `$key` inside the compare function? I can obviously make my own sorting function to accomplish this, but I want to use native sorting functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `use` keyword on your inner function that you pass to `usort`.

From the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the use language construct.

So, try this:

```
function sort_array_by_inner_key($array, $key) {
    usort($array, function($a, $b) use($key){
        return $a[$key] - $b[$key];
    });
    return $array;
}
```

This will work as you expect.

Or you can even do this, if you want:

```
function sort_array_by_inner_key(&$array, $key) {
    usort($array, function($a, $b) use($key){
        return $a[$key] - $b[$key];
    });
}
```

Now `sort_array_by_inner_key` will sort it in-place instead of returning it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Thanks.  I was just looking for that :-)

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful. i actually prefer returning functions, thats why i made it that way :)

Comment: @user2914191: Me too, I just figured I'd mention it anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    suggesting little enhancement for dynamic key and order based sorting if anyone is looking for the same


public static function sort2DArrayByKey($array, $key , $order = 'ASC') {
        usort($array, function($a, $b) use($key,$order){
            if($order == "DESC") {
                return $b[$key] - $a[$key];
            }
            else{
                return $a[$key] - $b[$key];
            }
        });
        return $array;
    }
```